# AJP worker threads hung

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, networking, ajp

CentOS 7 , java 1.8.131, tomcat 7.
this problem appears about once per week. Tomcat can't respond on any request.
Ajp threads hung while read AjpMessage from socket.
It hangs in native code. Problem disappearing when tomcat restarted.

when the problem appears I see 200 hanging threads (tomcat.maxthreads=200).
How can I solve this problem?

```
Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000001198fe520>, (a java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

Thread 83765: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=8, line=116 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=117, line=171 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=141 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=25, line=312 (Compiled frame)
 -
```

Comment: Hard to know without the code, but I usually see hanging threads caused by code that tries to access an  external resource (ftp server, JMS queue, database, ...) and this external resource does not respond.  The code must handle these cases (include a timeout, pool connections, ...).  I am used to debug things like that in WebSphere, where I would dump the threads (kill -3) and look at what they are trying to do, with a developer.  Something similar must exist for tomcat.

Comment: So its not about code, because thread hanging while read AjpMessage from Apache. Custom code starts to work after the AjpRequset have been read.

Comment: If you think it is between the AJP module and Tomcat, you could put all logs in debug mode and hopefully see something there.  The fact it is intermittent could indicate some network disturbance (high latency, cut off, ...).

Comment: Please post the rest of the stack trace of that thread dump. Are you sure those threads aren't just doing their normal job of waiting for incoming requests? That is their primary job...